# Failed to resolve endpoint CXF on JBoss Fuse 6.3

Tags: spring, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, fuseesb

Iam facing an issue while deploying a camel cxf webservice in Jboss Fuse 6.3.
The component is working fine in local instance but it is failing in other instance. It is going in a recursive loop and the logs are piling up with same exception.

Apache camel version - 2.17.0

Jboss EAP 6.4

Any help appreciated.

**Endpoint configuration:**

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="ApiReadEndpoint" xmlns:nms="urn:company:esb:services:CoreInsuranceRead:v01"
    address="{{esb.api.outread.contextpathurl}}"
    wsdlURL="wsdl/aoiRead/CoreInsuranceReadInterface.wsdl"
    endpointName="nms:SysTest"
    serviceName="nms:CoreInsuranceReadService">

    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
        <entry key="ws-security.validate.token" value="false" /> 
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wss4jInInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="authorizationInterceptor" />
     </cxf:inInterceptors>

</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

**Camel Route:**

```
<route id="APIReadServiceRoute" streamCache="true">
  <from id="ApiReadEndpoint" uri="cxf:bean:ApiReadEndpoint"/>
  <doTry id="_doTry1">
      <to id="_to1" uri="direct:ClaimRead"/>
      <doCatch id="_doCatch1">
          <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
          <handled>
              <constant>true</constant>
          </handled>
      </doCatch>
  </doTry>
</route>
```

**Error logs:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:ApiReadEndpoint due to: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
     Error creating bean with name 'ApiReadEndpoint': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:589) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.java:55)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean.getObject(CamelEndpointFactoryBean.java:60) [camel-spring-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean.getObject(CamelEndpointFactoryBean.java:38) [camel-spring-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:166) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1467) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1131) [spring-context-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:47) [camel-spring-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookup(CamelContextHelper.java:137) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:157) [camel-core-2.17.0.redhat-630310.jar:2.17.0.redhat-630310]
```

Comment: You have set the same id for endpoint and consumer `ApiReadEndpoint`. Not sure if it is real cause of this error (Possibly it could cause recursive initialization), but for sure it is not correct. Rename or remove id definition from consumer.

Comment: Yes that was the issue.worked like a charm.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved in comments. Issue was in identical assigned id `ApiReadEndpoint` for consumer and endpoint. This caused recursive endpoint initialization. After renaming or removing optional `id` attribute from consumer, the context started as expected.